# How to calculate same substring from given entire NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I wan to calculate total white space in given string.If total white space is more then 1 then I want to replace 2nd number of space with "\n"

For example: 
**My string is : "I like iPhone" . This string contains 3 space.
So I want o/p like this "I like \niPhone".**

This is just example. My string is not static. Give string is dynamic
How can I implement ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: But "I like iPhone" only contains 2 spaces.

Comment: Sorry check my I updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *givenString = @"I like iPhone ok";
NSArray *stringArray = [givenString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSString *string = @"";

for (int i = 0; i<stringArray.count; i++) {
    string = i==2 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",string,stringArray[i]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",string,stringArray[i]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot. This code is works grate. U save my time :)